# Setting List<CustomObject> = List<String> - having a brain dead moment

Tags: c#, .net, list, overloading, variable-assignment

I'm sure this is easy. Infact I'm sure I've done this before...

I have a class of MyClass which has 2 parameters TheString and SomeInt

Somewhere, in another class I declare an `List<MyClass> MyClassList` and a `List<String> StringList`

Both have the same number of items. I want this to set all "TheStrings" in each MyClass from MyClassList equal to the corresponding String from StringList

I set `MyClassList = StringList`

Now I know this wont work because they're different types. I think I've got to overload the assignment (=) operator but I can't see how this is done. I suppose I could always provide a method to call from MyClass, but that isn't quite so elegant. What would be the most elegant solution?

Thanks
Thomas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't overload the ***=*** operator. You could do an implicit conversion, example from MSDN:

```
public static implicit operator double(Digit d)
{
   return d.val;
}
```

However in case of lists I think the best solution is to use LINQ:

```
List<MyClass> list = (from value in StringList
                     select new MyClass { TheString = value }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Nowhere near enough information, but:

```
var customObjects = new List<CustomObject>(TheStringList.Select(s => new CustomObject { TheString = s }));
```

I didn't test this, but I wanted to show the idea that came to mind.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're looking for elegance and quite possibly magic when it sounds like a simple `for` loop should suffice. You've described the problem as having two equally sized lists, one of a particular class, another of strings. You want to set a string property on each class to the corresponding string in the opposite list (so presumably these are sorted and at matching indexes). All you need is a loop.

```
for (int index = 0; index = MyClassList.Count; index++)
{
     MyClassList[index].TheString = StringList[index];
}
```

Comment: I know I could that. In the end I did. Apparently you can't overload the assignment operator in c#! I went for MyClassList.ForEach(item => { ... }); Just feels bloaty :(